# Count pages in print area of another tab

Tags: excel, vba

**Aim**
Create an excel function that counts the number of pages on a different tab, but also respects the print area.

**What I've tried**
The following function works, but does not respect print areas, and strangely when recalculating changes it's output

```
Public Function countpa(Tabx As String) As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    countpa = Sheets(Tabx).PageSetup.Pages.Count
End Function
```

The following integrated function GET.DOCUMENT(50) seems to respect the page layout / print area, but I don't suceed to use it in a function that allows me to refer to a different tab

works when executed on tab

```
Sub ShowMe()
    MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)") & _
        " pages will be printed."
End Sub
```

does not work

```
Public Function countp(Tabx As String) As Long
   countp = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Get.Document(50," & Tabx & ")")
End Function
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to include a double quotation mark `""` within the string parts together with starting or ending quotation marks.

```
Public Function countp(Tabx As String) As Long
countp = ExecuteExcel4Macro("Get.Document(50,""" & Tabx & """)")
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Debug.Print countp("Sheet1") & " page(s) will be printed."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input - it works great in the immediate window. but unfortunately not as a function, any idea why that is ?

Comment: Glad I could help partially; Didn't find a workaround for tabular udfs: I don't know if this is a versioning issue or if it's impossible to execute them as Excel udf. - In any case it's risky to use it, as you don't know at which time ExecuteExcel4Macro will be deprecated at all.  :-;